# How to acquire skeletal joint data to text file from two kinect cameras in SkeletalViewer? (C++)

Tags: c++-cli, kinect, kinect-sdk

I am currently working on a project to use multiple kinect cameras to acquire x,y,z coordinates of skeletal data in SkeletalViewer. I have an idea to use the **KinectID** or **index** of different kinect cameras to extract the sets of skeletal joints data into **2 different text files**. But I am not sure if I am doing right. Please help to take a look at the modification below, or I will appreciate all your kind advice on other method to solve this problem.

In SkeletalViewer.h, I modified as following:

```
public:
FILE* mp3DFile0;
FILE* mp3DFile1;

char mText[1024];

INuiSensor *  m_pNuiSensor;
BSTR          m_instanceId;
array         SensorIndex;
```

In NuiImpl.cpp, I modified as following:

1) define array

```
ref class MyClass {
public:
    int m_i;
};

array<MyClass^>^ arrSensor() {
    int i;
    array< MyClass^ >^ local = gcnew array< MyClass^ >(2);

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        local[i] = gcnew MyClass;
        local[i]->m_i = i;
    }
    return local;
}
```

2) create array to store sensor index to do for loop later

```
HRESULT CSkeletalViewerApp::Nui_Init( )
{
    HRESULT  hr;
    bool     result;

    //create an array to store two file pointers
    FILE* mp3DFile[] = { mp3DFile0, mp3DFile1 };

    fopen_s(mp3DFile0, "D:/Kinect/KinectCam0.txt", "w+");
    fopen_s(mp3DFile1, "D:/Kinect/KinectCam1.txt", "w+");
    .
    .
    if ( !m_pNuiSensor )
    {
        hr = NuiCreateSensorByIndex(0, &m_pNuiSensor);
        //I am not sure about how to utilize this index in this case
    .
    .
    }

    if (NuiGetSensorCount(&m_pNuiSensor) > 1)
    {
        array< MyClass^ >^ SensorIndex;
        SensorIndex = arrSensor();
    }
}
```

3) use for loop to store data to different text file using index

```
void CSkeletalViewerApp::Nui_DrawSkeleton( const NUI_SKELETON_DATA & skel, int windowWidth, int windowHeight )
{   
    int i;
    int h;

    for (h = 0; h < 2; h++)
    {   
        //when index point to the current kinect
        if (SensorIndex[h] == &m_pNuiSensor)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < NUI_SKELETON_POSITION_COUNT; i++)
            {
                m_Points[i] = SkeletonToScreen(skel.SkeletonPositions[i], windowWidth, windowHeight);

                memset(mText, 0, 1024);

                sprintf(mText, "(%0.3f,%0.3f,%0.3f)", skel.SkeletonPositions[i].x, skel.SkeletonPositions[i].y, skel.SkeletonPositions[i].z);

                if (mp3DFile[h]) {
                    fputs((const char*)mText, mp3DFile[h]);
                }
            }

            if (mp3DFile[h]) {
                fputs("\n", mp3DFile[h]);
            }
        }
    }
    .
    .
}
```

I am a newbie in this Kinect programming. Thank you very much for your help! :)